# How to create an installer for javaee jar file to install it as a servicde using install4j

Tags: install4j

How to create an installer for javaee jar file to install it as a servicde using install4j? I have a jar file and its dependencies and want to create an installer which will install it as a service on  multiple platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example on how to create a service, invoke "Project->Open Sample Project" in the install4j IDE and open "hello.install4j" in the "hello" directory.

It contains a service launcher and actions that install and start the service.